# Hair Particle Instance Objects Inheriting Emitter Colours

Tags: texturing, particles, hair, instances

**Blender 2.9**

Hello. I have a bird model with UVs and texturing on it. I need to create realistic feathering. The bird model has a hair particle system. I created a custom feather shape and used the Particle Instance + Follow Path options so the feathering follows the hair system paths. This enables me to be able to groom the feathers for a more natural look.

The issue I am having is that unlike the hair system itself, I cannot get the feathers to inherit the coloured values of the bird based on the skin. I have tried many ways including 'from dupli/from instancer', following tutorials on linking instanced objects to emitter systems, looked at many blender forums and even asked in the Blender discord. No solution has worked so far.

All the ones out there (including the popular youtube videos for shading particles/instances) will only work if the instanced object uses a particle system, not the hair system.

[image: Feathers not inheriting skin pattern of the bird. Only displays the bird UVs within the feathering]

Here is the link to the drive with the files. If you're able to get this working, I would be so grateful!

[Bird](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1x2S34NMupnA-xmXgR8wu9xa-U2A-9DBX?usp=sharing)